# Is a potentially-throwing function signal-safe?

Tags: c++, exception, signals, undefined-behavior

According to [support.signal](https://eel.is/c++draft/support.signal#3),

> An evaluation is *signal-safe* unless it includes one of the following:
>
> - ...
> - throwing of an exception;
> - control entering a try-block or function-try-block;
> - ...
>
> A signal handler invocation has undefined behavior if it includes an evaluation that is not signal-safe.

Does it mean calling a potentially-throwing function, such as one declared with a `noexcept` specifier that evaluates to `false`, results in undefined behavior? Or is it only undefined behavior if the evaluation effectively results in an exception being thrown?

Here is an example:

```cpp
static void g() noexcept(false) {}
 
extern "C" void signal_handler(int sig)
{
    try {
        g(); // always UB
    }
    catch (...) {
    }

    g(); // always UB?
}
```

Comment: Per your quote, entering a `try` block is already undefined behavior in a signal handler, before we even get to calling `g`.

Comment: A signal handler has a VERY limited set of things it can do.  A thrown exception (even if caught and handled) is not one of them.

Comment: Considering `signal_handler` itself is `noexcept(false)`, it's probably fine?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Hence the comment "always UB" without a trailing question mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"throwing of an exception" should be taken literally, and precisely: an exception gets thrown. Nothing more, nothing less.

Entering a scope that potentially throws an exception is not the same thing. As long as the code does not actually throw an exception, signal safety is not violated.

`g()` does not end up throwing an exception, therefore, by itself, it is signal-safe. Even if it was not explicitly `noexcept(false)`, since it does not throw an exception it is signal safe.

`signal_handler()` enters a `try` block, which is not signal-safe. Entering it inside a signal handler is undefined behavior.

Comment: I both quoted and added the try-block in the question for the sake of comparison